# Simple SQL select in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, select

On my current project, to get a single value (select column from table where id=val), the previous programmer goes through using a datarow, datatable and an sqldatadapter (and of course sqlconnection) just to get that one value.

Is there an easier way to make a simple select query? In php, I can just use `mysql_query` and then `mysql_result` and I'm done.

It would be nice if I could just do:

```
SqlConnection conSql = new SqlConnection(ConnStr);
SomeSqlClass obj = new SomeSqlClass(sql_string, conSql);
conSql.Close();
return obj[0];
```

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Since you were asking for not only solutions, but also tips, I'd like to recommend you to take a look at LINQ, which is not only for database queries, but helps a lot!

Comment: +1: I must admire the alliteration in the question title

Comment: Also recommend the Enterprise Library Data Block.  It makes simple work of most db calls. 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203099.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at those tools.

Comment: Chris - it looks extremely verbose and ridiculous to start with, but most developers move these formalities into a data access layer (using a pattern such as Repository). The end result is only one or two lines of code to get everything you need. Combine this with LINQ and it's faster, less code, and maybe even more powerful than PHP.

Comment: Thanks Robert for the tip. He did have a method in a custom class of his for this purpose. But like I said, it was using more code than I thought was necessary. I'll look into LINQ. I've heard about it but I've never tried anything with it. Right now, I'm just getting the basics of C# under my belt.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can skip the `DataReader` and the `DataAdapter` and just call `ExecuteScalar()` on the sql command.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM whatever 
                                       WHERE id = 5", conn);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            newID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably use this solution for now. Thank you!

Comment: A point to be noted here, `ExecuteScalar` returns the first row of the first column in the result. It is better to use field name explicitly. Something like this is even better `select top 1 MyField ... sort by asc/desc` to get the required single value.

Comment: Add this namespace `using System.Data.SqlClient;`

Comment: Really, really nice and simple. Most of my stuff doesn't require single values. Thanks for the quick and easy one.

Answer (score 9):

You are probably looking for `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader`

```
Dictionary<int, string> users = new Dictionary<int, string>();
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Your connection string"))
{
    string query = "SELECT UserId, UserName FROM Users";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
    connection.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
            users.Add(reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetString(1));
    }
    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: +1 for using the reader.  But you shouldn't use column indexes!!!  Also, you don't need the connection.Close (It is taken care of with the "using" statement.)

Answer (score 5):

Actually, there is a method SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar() that will simply return the first field from the first row of the returned results. Just for you.

[.NET Framework Class Library
SqlCommand..::.ExecuteScalar Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)

> Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something very similar:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnStr))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql_string, conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    return cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use SqlCommands executeScalar function. Please look at the following link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx