# How to Display doctors ordered by number of performed surgeries

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have table `[Surgery_By]` table`[Surgery]` table`[Doctor]` i'm using ASP.NET with SQL Server :

The table `[Surgery_By]` contains the following columns:

```
1-ID (PK)
2-Surgery ID (FK)
3-Doctor ID (FK)
```

How to Display doctors ordered by number of performed surgeries ?

Comment: Can you show what you have so far?

Comment: sorry explain please .... i didnt understand ur quastion ?

Comment: Post your All table structure and data

Comment: table [Surgery]:
ID .... SurgeryDate ... SurgeryKind ... PatientID
//////
table [Doctor]:
ID .... FullName ... Speciality
//////
table [Patient]:
ID .... FullName ... BirthDate ... Address
//////
table [Surgery_By]:
ID .... SurgeryID ... DoctorID

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way

```
SELECT d.id, d.fullname, COUNT(s.id) total_surgeries
  FROM doctor d LEFT JOIN surgery_by s
    ON d.id = s.doctor_id
 GROUP BY d.id, d.fullname
 ORDER BY total_surgeries DESC
```

Sample output:

```
| ID |   FULLNAME | TOTAL_SURGERIES |
|----|------------|-----------------|
|  1 |   John Doe |               3 |
|  2 |   Jane Doe |               1 |
|  3 | Mark Smith |               0 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/51c35/1)** demo

Comment: You're very welcome. If it was what you were looking for please, consider to **[accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a stab in the dark.

```
Select Doctor.ID As DoctorID
    ,Count(*) As Count
From Doctor
    Join Surgery_By
    On Doctor.ID = Surgery_By.DoctorID 
Group By Doctor.DoctorID
Order By Count(*)
```

I am not sure if you want the table `Surgery` incorporated (but if you do, the join will be pretty straight forward - just be sure to add selected columns to the `Group By` statement.)

From ASP.NET, you may [select this data from a SQL Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504895/simple-sql-select-in-c).